# sending nick name to openfire server

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

1. I have built a chat application using strophe.js library with openfire sever. The problem I face is that ,I'm sending nickname from my application but i don't know whether openfire is picking this name and sending it to the other end. Is there a way to check nicknames of all the clients connected to openfire in admin console ?
2. This is the code for sending nickname,on each msg i push nickname.

code:

```
var rep = $msg({
to: JANE,
from: connection.jid
}).c("nick",{xmlns:'http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'}).t("anil");
connection.send(rep.tree());
```

in application logs i can see xml format lik this,

```
<body rid='630150802' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='3045bed3'>
  <message to='xyz.yyy.com' from='3045bed3@domaiin.com/3045bed3' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <nick xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>anil</nick>
  </message>
</body>
```

3. if i send the nick name along with msg with body,

logs looks like this,

```
<body rid='862711207' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='9f5d7b67'>
  <message to='xyz.yyy.com' from='9f5d7b67@domain.com/9f5d7b67' type='chat' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <nick xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>anil<body>hello</body></nick>
  </message>
</body>
```

nick name header ends after message body ends, but I want it to be like this:

```
<body>
  <message>
    <nick>anil</nick>
    <body>"chat text"</body>
  </message>
</body>
```

How do I close this nick name field before the body starts?

Comment: Nicknames in messages are intended for the other clients, not for the server itself. The server pass this element as is.

Comment: Is my code correct for sending nicknames?  Wat is the best way to send nick names?  And also can u see my 3rd point of my question and suggest solutuon.

Comment: Your code does not show how you add the "hello" body. Your example code does not match the produced result.

Comment: @Mickaël - this is my code 

var rep = $msg({
to: JANE,
from: connection.jid
}).c("nick",{xmlns:'http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'}).t("anil").c("body").t("hello");

Comment: Yes, your code is clearly wrong: You are explicitely adding hello body as child of nick.

Comment: @Mickaël - Can you suggest me what i  need to change to get an output in this form...
<body>
  <message>
    <nick>anil</nick>
    <body>"chat text"</body>
  </message>
</body>

how do i close nick field before i start body(chat) field .

Comment: @Mickaël - any suggestions on how i can change my code to get the output i posted... thanks